# Does the construction of a continuous function whose Fourier series diverges at one point get any easier if one allows jump discontinuities?

Tags: convergence-divergence, continuity, fourier-series, piecewise-continuity

More specifically, I seek a function $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ that satisfies

1. $f$ is $2\pi$-periodic
2. $f$ is continuous on $[0,2\pi]$ except at finitely many points
3. At every point of $\mathbb{R}$, the left- and right-hand limits of $f$ exist and are finite, and the value of $f$ is their average
4. There exists $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ so that the Fourier series of $f$ evaluated at $x_0$ either diverges or converges to a value not equal to $f(x_0)$.

Points 2. and 3. imply that $f$ is determined by its values on any full-measure set.

I know that there are examples (du Bois-Reymond, Fejer, Kolmogorov, etc) of even continuous functions that satisfy 1. and 4. above. I find those examples rather complicated. Does the above weakening of continuity make a simple construction available?

Comment: Condition 3 (and the usual theorems - eg convergence of Fourier series for functions of bounded variation) makes me think that an example is as hard as the usual ones mentioned of continuous functions with diverging Fourier series

Comment: @ Conrad: I tend to agree. Do you know any theorems for the _convergence_ of Fourier series at jump discontinuities that do not apply to points of continuity?

Comment: All that I know at least offhand are those that have convergence to the average lateral limits (if they exist, so in particular to the value if function continuos), so I do not think there are such - the idea is that the Fourier series behaves well around points where the function has countably many extrema locally and by symmetry of the Dirichlet Kernel one can always look at $\frac{1}{2}(f(x_0+\epsilon)+f(x_0-\epsilon))$, so good behaviour on both sides implies convergence to the average, while bad behaviour on one side has nothing to do with the other side

Comment: Very good question though